# C++ Invalid Argument to stof()/stoi() (std::invalid_argument: stoi: no conversion)

Tags: c++, string, casting, std

I have a program where I attempt to take a string value out of a vector and convert it into a float. The string is guaranteed to be a numerical value based on how I'm parsing the input data. When I attempt to run my program, I get the following error.

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stof: no conversion
Abort trap: 6
```

I traced where the issue was coming from, and it was where I was calling `stof()` to convert the obtained value from the vector into a float. The issue also persists when I call `stoi()` on the values as well. I used a typeid call to verify the value and dumped the type to the console.

```
type of there_list[2]: NSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE
val of there_list[2]: 10
```

I have absolutely no idea why this is the case, or what this even is for that matter, as my vector is clearly a vector of strings.

The code in question is the following:

```
string there(buffer);
vector<string> there_list = parse_word_list(there);

// Decide where to send the message next
// if the intended recipient (who the message is addressed to) is in range, send directly to recipient
cout << "type of there_list[2]: " << typeid(there_list[2]).name() << endl;
cout << "val of there_list[2]: " << there_list[2] << endl;


float dist_to_recipient = distance(sensor.getX(), sensor.getY(), stof(there_list[2]), stof(there_list[3]));
```

where `buffer` is a `char[]` that was used to read in input data from a server. My `parse_word_list(there)` call returns a string vector of the "words" contained in `there` delimited by spaces.

The function is basic, and looks like this

```
vector<string> parse_word_list(string phrase){

    istringstream parse(phrase);
    vector<string> word_list;

    // Traverse through all words 
    do {
        // Read a word
        string word; 
        parse >> word; 

        // Append the read word to the word_list
        word_list.push_back(word);

    } while(parse); // While there is more to read 
    return word_list;
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `there_list[3]`?

Comment: Is `there_list.size() >= 4`?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm .... so I'm real dumb and didn't recognize I was cutting off the string buffer by one index, so I was attempting to index `there_list[3]` when it didn't exist. Thanks for pointing that out.